# Spring Boot Health Endpoint not found in Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-boot-actuator

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and wrote a custom actuator Endpoint that uses the built-in Health Endpoint and wraps its content to a specific business-demanded format. The problem is that when i start the application normally everything works as expected, in the tests i however get an error that the `HealthController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint' that could not be found.`
Do you know where my mistake is?

The custom endpoint looks something like this:

```
@Endpoint(
  id = "custom-health"
)
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HealthController {

  private final HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;
  
  @ReadOperation
  public CustomHealthComponent health() {
      //some code that is mapping from the internally used HealthEndpoint models to the custom models
      return ...;
  }
```

This class is scanned on application start like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
  SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
  ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {
    //some classes...
})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {
  //some classes...
})
@ComponentScan(
  basePackages = {
    "health", <- this package contains the `HealthController` Component listed above
    //some packages...
  },
  excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = some exclusions...)
)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

And the test class in which i get the error:

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test1", "test2"})
public class TheFailingIT {
   //lots of tests that all fail with the specified error...
}
```

I also made following changes to the `test/resources/application.yaml` to activate the custom endpoint (i made the same changes in the real `application.properties` file and there it worked, in the tests unfortunately not)

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      discovery:
        enabled: false
      exposure:
        include: custom-health
      cors:
        allowed-methods: GET
        allowed-origins: "*"
      base-path: /basepath
    enabled-by-default: true
  health:
    defaults:
      enabled: false
    db:
      enabled: true
      
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: ALWAYS
```

PS: Few changes to the class names have been made. Also i tried to comment out irrelevant stuff. If there are any further questions to clarify the current codebase feel free to ask! Thanks in advance for the help.